# USB Stick shown in lsusb but not in lsblk

Tags: linux, usb, ntfs, usb-device, lsusb

I was trying to format an usb key with `mkfs.ntfs` to use it on windows.

When it reaches 80%, I got an error (don't remember it exactly) so I tried to remove the key and put it back.
But the key didn't show in /dev, nor in `fdisk`, nor in `lsblk`.

But I see it in `lsusb` output.

How can I fix this usb key to use it again ?

---

Edit : When i plug it and look into `dmesg` output, i see an error : 
`usb 1-4: device descriptor  error -110`

So the device is detected, but cannot be mapped to /dev cause of this error i think. I belive there is a (verry low level) way to repair it. 
(the device is listed in `/sys/class/scsi_host/`)

This is how `lsusb -v` show my device :

```
Bus 001 Device 041: ID 1e3d:198a Chipsbank Microelectronics Co., Ltd 
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1e3d Chipsbank Microelectronics Co., Ltd
  idProduct          0x198a 
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           0 
  iProduct                0 
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
```

And here is the output of `dmesg` :

```
[123587.211296] usb-storage 1-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[123587.212372] scsi host1: usb-storage 1-4:1.0
[123608.945088] usb 1-4: reset high-speed USB device number 40 using xhci_hcd
[123609.072855] usb 1-4: device firmware changed
[123609.073005] usb 1-4: USB disconnect, device number 40
[123609.198787] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 41 using xhci_hcd
[123614.565846] usb 1-4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[123614.801071] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=1e3d, idProduct=198a, bcdDevice= 1.00
[123614.801076] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[123614.804628] usb-storage 1-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[123614.806186] scsi host1: usb-storage 1-4:1.0
[123636.592122] usb 1-4: reset high-speed USB device number 41 using xhci_hcd
```

Comment: If there is 'only confusion' of the file system, you may be able to repair it, but the stick might be damaged beyond repair (a hardware error). [This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) helps you to analyze the problem, and it you are lucky, solve it.

Comment: I'dlike to use the methods described on this link, but i can't cause i don't see the drive in lsblk, and it is not mapped in /dev.

Comment: Have you done the mechanical/physical stuff (rebooting, unplugging other USB devices, trying all USB ports, trying in other computers ...)? - If you cannot see the drive as a device `/dev/sdx`, you cannot use it.

Comment: I've already tried, and on a windows system too. But the drive is detected by the kernel when i plug it, and it's listed in `/sys/class/scsi_host/`
So i belive there is a way to comunicate with it

Comment: I am afraid that it is damaged beyond repair, but I wish you good luck. There might be a method, that I don't know.